# Git unignore child directory of ignored directory

Tags: git

I am trying to set up a gitignore file for a Wordpress site. Here is what I have so far:

```
# Ignore everything in the root except the "wp-content" directory.
/*
!.gitignore
!/wp-content/

# Ignore everything in the "wp-content" directory, except the "plugins"
# and "themes" directories.
/wp-content/*
!/wp-content/plugins/
!/wp-content/themes/

# Ignore everything in the "plugins" directory, except the plugins you
# specify (see the commented-out examples for hints on how to do this.)
/wp-content/plugins/*
!/wp-content/plugins/coemans-site-plugin/

# Ignore everything in the "themes" directory, except the themes you
# specify (see the commented-out example for a hint on how to do this.)
/wp-content/themes/*
!/wp-content/themes/bg-mobile-first/
```

This works fine for the plugins folder, but only the bg-mobile-first folder gets added, not its contents. If I replace bg-mobile-first with the other theme in the themes folder (genesis) the whole folder and everything in it does get added.

I am new to git, so I'm probably missing something obvious, but I've been searching for a while and haven't come up with a solution yet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "only the bg-mobile-first folder gets added, not its contents"? Git cannot add a folder, it can add only contents, i.e., the files in the folder.

Comment: sorry, I can't close the question just yet, but it is solved. there was a rogue git folder in the bg-mobile-first folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating a fresh repo for another site and there it's working as expected so consider this closed.

Comment: Could you close the question?